# Twitter's Bootstrap how to get the same layout for min-width 768px and min-width 992px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap 3 and i need to have the same layout for both min-widths 768px and 992px.
I don't want to edit the original Bootstrap CSS instead i have a bootstrap-overwrite.css that i used to customize the layout.
Is there an easy way to "disable" min-width 992px so that it uses the same css for 768px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this...Reduce the `container` width in your `bootstrap-overwrite.css`

Here is the code, Place it at the end of css

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
```